# WCF : Migrating from .net Framework to .net Core

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-core

Evaluating moving from .Net Framework to .Net Core. The bit that i am unable to answer is migrating WCF Services. The options that come to mind are

1. Web API
2. Named Pipes
3. Use an external project e.g. https://github.com/jacqueskang/IpcServiceFramework

Is there any other option apart from the ones listed above ?

Comment: Welcome! Note that questions about recommending a specific, tool, library, etc. are off topic here. If you could formulate your question about a particular issue you have with either of those technologies you suggested, that would be a better fit.

Comment: @Christian.K thanks for the feedback, will update the question

Comment: Its not quite clear what you are asking. What is it you want to know? Which technologies to use? Thats your choice. If you have a specific question about one of those technologies, ask away